# Notification badge counter for custom web app in Microsoft Teams

Tags: javascript, reactjs, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I am working on a custom webApp for Microsoft Teams, I would like to manipulate the badge notification for my App. I need to add a counter like teams does for new messages or another symbol to indicate different actions in my app.

Is there a way to do this? using a sdk, api, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you developing any Teams app? And in that Teams app you need to manipulate the badge notification?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT  yes am working on  messaging app if i receive any message i want to show the message count in my app icon just like any other teams tab